# COM4J: Generating code for oleacc.dll -> Can not handle **byte as parameter

Tags: java, c, com, com4j

When I try to analyse and create the java processing I get the following error:

> C:\Users\TAAKEMA6\java\com4j>java -jar tlbimp.jar -o wsh -p test.wsh %WINDIR%\sy
>   stem32\oleacc.dll
>
> Generating definitions from Accessibility
>
> Unable to handle the type byte**
>     method GetIdentityString
>     interface IAccIdentity
>
> Unable to handle the type byte**
>     method ComposeHwndIdentityString
>     interface IAccPropServices
>
> Unable to handle the type byte**
>     method ComposeHmenuIdentityString
>     interface IAccPropServices

As you can see the byte** (pointer of pointer) is not supported which baffles me. Any work around or something I can do to get things back in order?